# Accessing HostingEnvironment.MapPath() within class called by webservice / website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, class

I have a project which contains shared functionality that can be used both by a ASP.NET WebApplication and a WCF Service.

The shared project is a Class Library, and has some dependencies on files.

Normally I would simply call `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` in order to resolve these dependencies, however this isn't possible in this context since `System.Web` isn't available (it's a class library).

Is my only real option passing the absolute path to the Class Library?  This would require me to do some further processing as it would be the root for the respective projects, and not the root of the Class Library.

Comment: you can add reference to System.Web in a class library project,just  add System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll along with the System.Web and System.Configuration

Comment: The problem with that is it returns the absolute path for the project that called the Class Library, not the location of the Class Library itself.  I think I'll probably have to go down the reflection route.

Comment: Have you tried System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get root of class library?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've found the following solution:

- Set the properties on the dependent files: **Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer**
- This copies the files into the bin folder of the *Hosting Environment* (so it will copy it into either the WCF Service or the WebApplication from the Class Library)
- `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` then returns this location

The difference is the files are being copied *cross project* when building (I didn't know `copy if newer` did this).  I can therefore access the files from the applications' bin (and not from the Class Library as I was attempting before).